# A request for an overview of the cranial nerves

Tags: neuroanatomy, literature, cranial-nerves

Is there any resource that contains motor and sensory innervations, or pathways of all the twelve cranial nerves (i.e., cranial nerve I to XII)?

I have found [this book chapter on the cranial nerves](http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/patestas/chapters/15.pdf), but it is too broad for me -  I'm still at high school.

Comment: A lot of the information that you are looking for *is* in the book chapter, but I can understand how it might be overwhelming.  Unfortunately, anything "easier" is probably going to be too cursory and sugar-coated, so you may just have to slog through it and cherry pick what you need.  Also, you're in the perfect spot to ask specific questions about the material already! :)

Comment: "Too broad"?  to me that means something lacks detail, isn't specific enough.  It sounds like you find that chapter too dense or too deep.  Can you clarify?  
What is the context, what do you already know, and what do you need to know?  (and what do you not need to know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are after, but I (as have others that commented on this question) interpret your question as "*The linked chapter contains too much technical information*". Quite frankly, after scanning the book chapter, I have to agree with you. Therefore I have sought for a quick overview image of all the cranial nerves including their sensory and motor targets.


[**Encyclopedia Britannica**](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/621522/vagus-nerve) has published all the cranial nerves and their sensory and motor innervations in a single comprehensive figure:

[image: Cranial Nerves]
<sup>Cranial Nerves and their targets. Source: [**Encyclopedia Britannica**](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/621522/vagus-nerve)</sup>

I can highly recommend this online encyclopedia. Their articles are more concise and better accessible than similar topics on wikipedia. Moreover, this encyclopedia is not freely editable by everyone on the planet, and everything I have seen so far on their website is credible.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @Ridho - my pleasure! :)

Comment: Very nice find!

Answer (score 0):

If you're still learning the names and functions of all 12 cranial nerves, something like this page may help you get ready for more in depth material like the chapter you found.
https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/cranial.html

I like the fact that they include activities for each nerve to help give you one more way to remember their functions.